# how to make common join function in codeigniter for listing

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord, join

i have one join function in codeigniter for listing but it joins only two tabels, for three tables i have to use another function and so on is there any way to make these functions common for any num of joins
**Model code**

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->load->database();
}

//listing with join for two tabels
public function get_joinlist($table,$value,$table2,$condi,$join_type,$order_by,$order,$where,$limit, $offset)
{
        $this->db->select($value);
            $this->db->join($table2,$condi,$join_type);
    $this->db->order_by($order_by,$order);
    $this->db->where($where);
    return $query= $this->db->get($table, $limit, $offset);
}
//listing with join for three tabels
public function get_joinlist1($table,$value,$table2,$condi1,$join_type1,$table3,$condi2,$join_type2,$where,$order_by,$order)
{
    $this->db->select($value);
    $this->db->join($table2, $condi1,$join_type1);
    $this->db->join($table3, $condi2,$join_type2);
    $this->db->where($where);
    $this->db->order_by($order_by,$order);
    return $this->db->get($table);
}
```

Comment: You could put the join params in an array and then loop through them to access them in the function?

Comment: do u need to compulsory write query using Active Record class......

Comment: Thanks for the reply everyone
@Venkat Not actually but my model conatins all the queries written in active content

Comment: k no problem dude. I do follow normal query rule in my all applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a very simple example to get you started

Construct `$joins` as array:

```
$joins = array(
    array(
        'table' => 'table2',
        'condition' => 'table2.id = table1.id',
        'jointype' => 'LEFT'
    ),
);
```

Example function handling joins as an array:

```
public function get_joins($table, $columns, $joins)
{
    $this->db->select($columns)->from($table);
    if (is_array($joins) && count($joins) > 0)
    {
        foreach($joins as $k => $v)
        {
            $this->db->join($v['table'], $v['condition'], $v['jointype']);
        }
    }
    return $this->db->get()->result_array();
}
```

Comment: oh k got it ,i will try this and get back if any issue is there,Thank you very much

Comment: @NishantLad Good luck champ

Comment: did u get anything on yesterday's question of pagination?

Comment: @Dale
Many Thanks.. It Helped me making the common Join Query.. :)